# array of pointers to vector of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

As someone indicated, it looks using vectors of arrays is usually more reasonable than using array of pointers; So here I have an array of pointers which I'd like to convert to vectors of arrays:

```
char ** ptr;    
char * ptrContiguous;

ptr = new char*[numChannels];
ptrContiguous = new char[x*y*byteSize*nC*nM*nZ*nT];
char * p = ptrContiguous;

for(int i = 0; i < numChannels; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = p;
    p += x*y*byteSize;                          

}
```

My questions are: only ptr needs to be converted to vector right? and someone can write some simple code illustrating the array to vector conversion? Thanks.

Comment: You'd be even better off converting this to a vector of strings - `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: can you write some simple code that will really help. Thanks.

Comment: @NickXTsui `std::vector<std::string> myvec( ptr, ptr+numChannels);`

Comment: @KitsuneYMG then the rest is the same? How do I do the for loop to assign ptr[i] in the sense of myvec?

Comment: And ptr should be still kept as a char**? I thought the point is to use a vector to replace a  char*[]

Comment: What is the source/purpose of ptrContiguous? I presume you're receiving a channel listing in the form of a single, contiguous block of text. Is it zero-terminated (does each string have a '\0' character to indicate the end of string?) or space padded or something? If you want "someone [to] write some simple code illustrating the [...] conversion" you might want to start by providing a [simple, self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/) to work from - it doesn't have to be your complete program, just enough for reference. This may be a good start: http://ideone.com/l7jI5u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your actual code :

```
char ** ptr;    
char * ptrContiguous;

ptr = new char*[numChannels];
ptrContiguous = new char[x*y*byteSize*nC*nM*nZ*nT];
char * p = ptrContiguous;

for(int i = 0; i < numChannels; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = p;
    p += x*y*byteSize;                          

}
```

Now, if you use vector from the STL, your code becomes this one :

```
std::vector<std::string> ptr;
ptr.resize(numChannels);

std::string ptrContiguous;
ptrContiguous.resize(x*y*byteSize*nC*nM*nZ*nT);

const int part_size = x*y*byteSize;
for(int i = 0; i < numChannels; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = std::string(ptrContiguous.begin() + i * part_size, ptrContiguous.begin() + (i+1) * part_size);                          
}
```

Also, [this link about vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) and [about strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) should help you. This is the code I suggest you without knowing what's the purpose of `ptrContiguous`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the function I used to use like delete ptr[i], or return ptr[i], all these return errors, seems string to char* has problems?

Comment: @NickXTsui with vectors and strings, you don't need delete and new. If you want to return `ptr[i]`, then your function definition should be this form : `std::string getPtrAtPosi(/*something here maybe*/) { ... }`. If you want to return `ptr`, the function should be like this form : `std::vector<std::string> getPtrAtPosi(/*something here maybe*/) { ... }`

Comment: My pointers pointing to char*. basically a piece of buffer representing images. So std::string can represent images?

Comment: @NickXTsui if you really want a vector of bytes (values between 0 and 255), in that case I suggest you to use `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (renamed some variables for code clarity, using C-style memory management since this is essentially C code, although let me know if you are unfamiliar with `malloc` and `free`):

```
char **short_strings; // short_strings[i] is the ith "short string"
char *long_string;

ptr = malloc(sizeof(char*) * num_short_strings);
long_string = malloc(sizeof(char) * num_short_strings * short_string_length);

char *p = long_string;

for(int i = 0; i < num_short_strings; i++)
{
    short_strings[i] = p;
    p += sizeof(char) * short_string_length;
}
```

Note that neither C++ `new`/`delete` nor C-style `malloc` and `free` will allow you to deallocate the memory for `short_strings[i]` (for example by calling `free(short_strings[i])` or `delete[] short_strings[i]`.  This is because these dynamic memory allocators hand out memory in chunks, and `free` and `delete` only allow you to delete the entire chunk you were handed.  If you want to be able to delete the short strings individually you will need to reallocate memory per short string, and `strcpy`, etc.